# what is the best way to show test results report for Selenium Maven setup

Tags: maven, ant, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am setting up maven for selenium webdriver by using JUNIT.

So can any one suggest me what is the best way to show test results reports ?

And if possible can you send pom.xml as well if you have good one.

Thanks
Raju

Answer (score 0):

For test results reports, I simply copy the test-output directory into a tomcat server where the people who need to see it can do so.

Below is my pom.xml. I realize that I do need to update my selenium version, but this should get you a good start.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>VINCI_DART_Automation</groupId>
  <artifactId>VINCI_DART_Automation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi Darth, Thank you for your post... I think you are not specified junit dependency and How to run the project... Shall I use mvn clean install from command prompt, or mvn test .... Can you please help me.

Comment: @Raju are you using eclipse? If so, just install maven with Eclipse as an add on.